# SharePoint 2010 ribbon controls hidden behind iframe content

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have an iframe in one of my application pages and whenever I load that page, all the ribbon controls i.e. the Site Actions menu and the User menu dont work. I mean when I click on them nothing happens. After I while I realized they were hidden behind the iframe. I tried using the Jquery bgiframe plugin on the ribbon container but that didn't work either.

**UPDATE 1:**
This is so weird! I just had to end the iframe tag like this `</iframe>` instead of `/>` and now the ribbon controls work!! Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an iframe shim: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/entry.php?249-A-better-Iframe-Shim

Comment: Whelton I actually need my iframe to behind the menu but the solution you proposed does the reverse.

Comment: No, the problem is related to iframes always appearing over the top of content regardless of z-index. An iframe shim is a hacky technique of positioning a div over the top of the iframe which then makes the ifram appear behind the content.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to place the IFrame in a  with a z-index? `<div style="display:block;position:absolute;top:0px;z-index:999;">YOUR FRAME HERE</div>`

Comment: Sharepoint can be a bit hooky when it comes to UI. I almost always create a custom layout to avoid Iframes or use a page viewer PAGE VIEWER: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx   CUSTOM LAYOUT: http://chrisonsharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-2010-page-layouts-not.html

Comment: Chris, check out my update above. I've solved the problem. But its so weird!

Comment: Yea, bad markup will do that. It makes sense though, if the IFRAME isnt closed correctly the page will do weird things. What you can try next time is use Mozilla and the FireBug addon. Evaluate the HTML markup with it.